# SQL to find curly brackets in a JSON file

Tags: sql

I am reading a JSON file to find if the file has data.
If it has data the file would look like

```
{"transactions":[{"id":"132482","postingId":"754","studentId":"12345"}
```

If the file has no data it would look like

```
{}
```

I am trying to email the user if the file has data.
I tried `regex [{}],^{},/{/},^{(*)}$` to check for no data and not to email.
All these expression failed.

```
SELECT '{"transactions":[{"id":"132482","postingId":"754","studentId":"602000335"}' value
FROM dual
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('{"transactions":[{"id":"132482","postingId":"754","studentId":"602000335"}', '^{(*)}$');
```

Am I missing something.

Comment: If the file has no data it's going to have `{}` so why use a regex when you can just check for that specific value?

Comment: I need a regex to use it in my automic application manager .

Comment: Why though? You are looking for the string `{}` you just said that, so why would you use regex to search for the value when you can just search for `value = '{}'`? If you are worried about newlines or spaces just replace them.

Comment: Application manager will accept only regexp on {} .

Comment: I think {} refers to an object in JSON file and that is why i need a regex

Comment: No... JSON is text... The only time it's "an object" is when you parse it into a data structure in memory (either in JS or in your language of choice). This is text, regex works on text.

Comment: Good to know its a text. Still it did not work .

Answer (score 0):

use regex :

`^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$`

---

Match strings that have letters and numbers. If a string does not have letters and numbers, it will not match.

```
SELECT '{"transactions":[{"id":"132482","postingId":"754","studentId":"602000335"}' value
FROM dual
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('{"transactions":[{"id":"132482","postingId":"754","studentId":"602000335"}', '^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$');
```

Comment: Thankyou . It did not work to get just the braces. What would be the regexp to get only transactions and not the rest of the string ?

Comment: If you are looking at pulling a piece of JSON out of a JSON snippet, use the JSON tools that come with your SQL database to select the JSON properties you want. What database is this, REGEXP_LIKE sounds like Oracle

Comment: Yes, it is oracle